# rspec ActiveStorage::Attachment.count wont change

Tags: rspec, rspec-rails, rails-activestorage

I try to test my API with rspec by an update of `company_logo` of my `Shop` model.

When I fire a request against the API with Postman with a file attached it saves correctly. So the Controller#action seems working proberly and I also get an URL back:

```json
{
    "name": "Sipes-Runte",
    "xml_feed": null,
    "slug": "sipes-runte",
    "url": "http://beier.co/ivey.kilback",
    "company_logo": {
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f8115e92010b47d1a657825a769b221e00f09b9d/thomasz%20portrait.jpeg",
        "signed_id": "eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBDZz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--f8115e92010b47d1a657825a769b221e00f09b9d"
    }
```

This is the controller:

```rb
  def update
    if @shop.update(shop_params)
      # following line is optional to see if its working (It didn't)
  @shop.company_logo.attach(params.dig(:shop, :company_logo)) if logo_params.present? # 
      render json: @shop, serializer: ShopSerializer
    else
      render json: @shop.errors, status: :ok
    end
```

But I have no clue why my rspec tests are failing:

Approach one:

```rb
   subject { patch shop_url(shop), params: params, headers: valid_headers(admin), as: :json }

        let(:params) { { shop: { name: "SHopName", company_logo: company_logo } } }
        let(:shop) { Shop.create! valid_attributes }
        let(:company_logo) { fixture_file_upload('400x400.png') }

        it 'returns status created' do
          subject
          expect(response).to have_http_status :ok
        end # works == GREEN

        it 'creates a blob ' do
          expect { subject }.to change { ActiveStorage::Blob.count }.from(0).to(1)
        end
      end
# FAILS with
# expected `ActiveStorage::Blob.count` to have changed from 0 to 1, but did not change
```

second approach:

```rb
        it "updates the company_logo" do
          subject
          expect(shop.company_logo).to be_attached
        end
# FAILS with:
# to be truthy, got false
```

That was my third approach:

```rb
      it "updates the company_logo" do
        shop = Shop.create! valid_attributes
        company_logo = fixture_file_upload('400x400.png', 'image/png')
        expect {
          patch shop_url(shop),
                params: { shop: { company_logo: company_logo } }, headers: valid_headers(shop.user), as: :json
        }.to change(ActiveStorage::Attachment, :count).by(1)
      end
# FAILS with
# expected `ActiveStorage::Attachment.count` to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
# I got that snippet from this tutorial: https://www.zweitag.de/blog/active-storage-rails-api-apps/
```

I can see, that the params are contained in the request (`tempfile`, `original_filename` and so on are present...

*Any ideas to get this green?*

I only wanna get sure, that the files are saved.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I got it:

I had to remove `as: :json` as well modifiying the headers:

FROM :

```
  def valid_headers(user = self.user)
    {
      "Authorization" => token_generator(user.id),
      "Content-Type" => "application/json",
      "Accept" => "application/json"
    }
  end 
   subject { patch shop_url(shop), params: params, headers: valid_headers(user), as: :json }
```

to

```
  def valid_multipart_headers(user = self.user)
    {
      "Authorization" => token_generator(user.id)
    }
  end

   subject { patch shop_url(shop), params: params, headers: valid_multipart_headers(user) }
```